# Use multiple value color scss

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm importing this `scss file (colors.scss)` which contains

> $white: #fff;
>
> $black: #000;
>
> $mat-red: ( 50: #ffebee, 100: #ffcdd2, 200: #ef9a9a, 300: #e57373, 400: #ef5350, 500: #f44336, 600: #e53935, 700: #d32f2f, 800: #c62828, 900: #b71c1c, A100: #ff8a80, A200: #ff5252, A400: #ff1744, A700: #d50000, contrast: ( 50: $black-87-opacity, 100: $black-87-opacity, 200: $black-87-opacity, 300: $black-87-opacity, 400: $black-87-opacity, 500: white, 600: white, 700: white, 800: $white-87-opacity, 900: $white-87-opacity, A100: $black-87-opacity, A200: white, A400: white, A700: white, ));

When I import `colors.scss` & I use `$white` or `$black` it works fine. But when I try to use `$mat-red` like in this example

```
app-root {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: $mat-red;
  }
```

I get this error

> Module build failed:
>   $mat-red: ( 50: #ffebee, 100: #ffcdd2, 200: #ef9a9a, 300: #e57373, 400: #ef5350, 500: #f44336, 600: #e53935, 700: #d32f2f, 800: #c62828, 900: #b71c1c, A100: #ff8a80, A200: #ff5252, A400: #ff1744, A700: #d50000, contrast: ( 50: $black-87-opacity, 100: $black-87-opacity, 200: $black-87-opacity, 300: $black-87-opacity, 400: $black-87-opacity, 500: white, 600: white, 700: white, 800: $white-87-opacity, 900: $white-87-opacity, A100: $black-87-opacity, A200: white, A400: white, A700: white, ));
>            ^
>         (50: #ffebee, 100: #ffcdd2, 200: #ef9a9a, 300: #e57373, 400: #ef5350, 500: #f44336, 600: #e53935, 700: #d32f2f, 800: #c62828, 900: #b71c1c, A100: #ff8a80, A200: #ff5252, A400: #ff1744, A700: #d50000, contrast: (50: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87), 100: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87), 200: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87), 300: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87), 400: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87), 500: white, 600: white, 700: white, 800: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.87), 900: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.87), A100: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87), A200: white, A400: white, A700: white)) isn't a valid CSS value.

Comment: it's simple : the value is invalid ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared a map of colors. You need to retrieve the desired color by:

```
.color{
  color: map-get($mat-red, 50); // 50 as an example of key in $mat-red
}
```